# Flask interface not redirecting correctly to results.html page

Tags: python, html, flask, methods, import

I'm trying to create a Flask interface with two buttons. Based on which button I press, I expect a different behavior. However, I am encountering an issue: while I can navigate to the `insert_data.html` page, it throws an error when it should redirect me to the `results.html` page.

```
import pandas as pd from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(name)

@app.route("/creazione_squadra", methods=["POST"]) def creazione_squadra(): if request.method == "POST": choice = request.form["choice"] if choice == "creazione_squadra": dataset = pd.read_csv("C", sep=",") dataset2 = pd.read_csv("C, sep=",")

# Leggi i valori dal form
        soglia_voto_minimo = float(request.form.get("soglia_voto_minimo", 0))
        soglia_voto_massimo = float(request.form.get("soglia_voto_massimo", 10))
        soglia_assist_minimo = float(request.form.get("soglia_Ass_minimo", 0))
        soglia_rigori_minimi_segnati = float(request.form.get("soglia_rigori_minimi_segnati", 0))
        soglia_rp_minimi_parati = float(request.form.get("soglia_rp_minimi_parati", 0))
        soglia_rc_minimi_calciati = float(request.form.get("soglia_rc_minimi_calciati", 0))
        soglia_r_errati_max = float(request.form.get("soglia_r_errati_max", 0))
        soglia_amm_max = float(request.form.get("soglia_amm_max", 0))
        soglia_esp_max = float(request.form.get("soglia_esp_max", 0))
        soglia_au_max = float(request.form.get("soglia_au_max", 0))

        # Filtra i giocatori in base ai criteri specificati per ciascun ruolo
        for i in range(0,1):
            if dataset["Nome"][i] in dataset2["Nome"].values:
                portieri_selezionati = dataset[
                    (dataset['Mv'] >= soglia_voto_minimo) & (dataset['Mv'] < soglia_voto_massimo) & 
                    (dataset['Pv'] > 10) & (dataset['R'] == 'P') & 
                    (dataset['Rp'] >= soglia_rp_minimi_parati) & 
                    (dataset['Amm'] <= soglia_amm_max) & (dataset['Esp'] <= soglia_esp_max) & 
                    (dataset['Au'] <= soglia_au_max)
                ].sort_values(by='Fm', ascending=False)

                difensori_selezionati = dataset[
                    (dataset['Fm'] >= soglia_voto_minimo) & (dataset['Fm'] < soglia_voto_massimo) & (dataset['Ass'] >= soglia_assist_minimo) & (dataset['R+'] >= soglia_rigori_minimi_segnati) &
                    (dataset['R'] == 'D') & 
                    (dataset['Rc'] >= soglia_rc_minimi_calciati) & (dataset['R-'] <= soglia_r_errati_max) &
                    (dataset['Amm'] <= soglia_amm_max) & (dataset['Esp'] <= soglia_esp_max) & 
                    (dataset['Au'] <= soglia_au_max)
                ].sort_values(by='Fm', ascending=False)

                centrocampisti_selezionati = dataset[
                    (dataset['Fm'] >= soglia_voto_minimo) & (dataset['Fm'] < soglia_voto_massimo) & (dataset['Ass'] >= soglia_assist_minimo) & (dataset['R+'] >= soglia_rigori_minimi_segnati) &
                    (dataset['R'] == 'C') & 
                    (dataset['Rc'] >= soglia_rc_minimi_calciati) & (dataset['R-'] <= soglia_r_errati_max) &
                    (dataset['Amm'] <= soglia_amm_max) & (dataset['Esp'] <= soglia_esp_max) & 
                    (dataset['Au'] <= soglia_au_max)
                ].sort_values(by='Fm', ascending=False)

                attaccanti_selezionati = dataset[
                    (dataset['Fm'] >= soglia_voto_minimo) & (dataset['Fm'] < soglia_voto_massimo) & (dataset['Ass'] >= soglia_assist_minimo) & (dataset['R+'] >= soglia_rigori_minimi_segnati) &
                    (dataset['R'] == 'A') & 
                    (dataset['Rc'] >= soglia_rc_minimi_calciati) & (dataset['R-'] <= soglia_r_errati_max) &
                    (dataset['Amm'] <= soglia_amm_max) & (dataset['Esp'] <= soglia_esp_max) & 
                    (dataset['Au'] <= soglia_au_max)
                ].sort_values(by='Fm', ascending=False)

                # Seleziona i migliori giocatori per ciascun ruolo
                portieri_finali = portieri_selezionati.head(3)
                difensori_finali = difensori_selezionati.head(8)
                centrocampisti_finali = centrocampisti_selezionati.head(8)
                attaccanti_finali = attaccanti_selezionati.head(6)
                # Combina i giocatori di tutti i ruoli per formare la squadra completa
                squadra_fantacalcio = pd.concat([portieri_finali, difensori_finali, centrocampisti_finali, attaccanti_finali])

    return redirect(url_for("squadra"))  # Reindirizza alla pagina "squadra"
@app.route("/squadra", methods=["GET"]) def squadra(): return render_template("squadra.html")

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"]) def index(): if request.method == "POST": choice = request.form["choice"] if choice == "creazione_squadra": return redirect(url_for("squadra")) return render_template("index.html")

if name == "main": 
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

Comment: Please fix the code, there's a missing or extra double-quote somewhere. And, (1) consider providing a [mre] rather than a copy-paste job, (2) please provide the complete traceback/error. These will improve the quality of answers.